# Is possible install windows 11 in dell Vostro 5470?

Tags: windows, dell-vostro

When I tried installing Windows 11 in my Dell Vostro 5470 I always receive the message:

> This PC doesn't meet the minimum system requirements to install this version of Windows...

I have an Intel core i7-4510U CPU 2.00GHz
8 GB of RAM memory and 500GB of HD.

I tried different configurations for the BIOS. But not working. Can you help me?

Comment: Your cpu is simply too old. There is nothing you can do without buying a new computer.

Comment: Yes you can>>>>https://pureinfotech.com/create-windows-11-bootable-usb-unsupported-pc-rufus/